# Is there a straightforward way to write to a file open in r+ mode without overwriting existing bytes?

Tags: python, file, io

I have a text file test.txt, with the following contents:

```
Thing 1. string
```

And I'm creating a python file that will increment the number every time it gets run without affecting the rest of the string, like so.

Run once:

```
Thing 2. string
```

Run twice:

```
Thing 3. string
```

Run three times:

```
Thing 4. string
```

Run four times:

```
Thing 5. string
```

This is the code that I'm using to accomplish this.

```
file = open("test.txt","r+")

started = False
beginning = 0 #start of the digits
done = False
num = 0

#building the number from digits
while not done:
        next = file.read(1)
        if ord(next) in range(48, 58): #ascii values of 0-9
                started = True
                num *= 10
                num += int(next)
        elif started: #has reached the end of the number
                done = True
        else: #has not reached the beginning of the number
                beginning += 1

num += 1
file.seek(beginning,0)
file.write(str(num))
```

This code works, so long as the number is not 10^n-1 (9, 99, 999, etc) because in those cases, it writes more bytes than were previously in the number. As such, it will override the characters that follow.

So this brings me to the point. I need a way to write to the file that overwrites previously bytes, which I have, and a way to write to the file that does not overwrite previously existing bytes, which I don't have. Does such a mechanism exist in python, and if so, what is it?

I have already tried opening the file using the line `file = open("test.txt","a+")` instead. When I do that, it always writes to the end, regardless of the seek point.

`file = open("test.txt","w+")` will not work because I need to keep the contents of the file while altering it, and files opened in any variant of w mode are wiped clean.

I have also thought of solving my problem using a function like this:

```
#file is assumed to be in r+ mode
def write(string, file, index = -1):
        if index != -1:
                file.seek(index, 0)
        remainder = file.read()
        file.seek(index)
        file.write(remainder + string)
```

But I also want to be able to expand the solution to larger files, and reading the rest of the file single-handedly changes what I'm trying to accomplish from being O(1) to O(n). It also seems very non-Pythonic, since it seeks to accomplish the task in a less-than-straightforward way.

It would also make my I/O operations inconsistent: I would have class methods (`file.read()` and `file.write()`) to read from the file and write to it replacing old characters, but an external function to insert without replacing.

If I make the code inline, rather than a function, it means I have to write several of the same lines of code every time I try to write without replacing, which is also non-Pythonic.

To reiterate my question, is there a more straightforward way to do this, or am I stuck with the function?

Comment: So to clarify, you want to insert into a file and push everything else farther back?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: No, if you want to insert into a file, you will generally have to re-write the entire remainder of the file. It has nothing to do with python or pythonic, that's just how files work.

Comment: `When I do that, it always writes to the end, regardless of the seek point.` It shouldn't be doing that. It *should* be overwriting the bytes at your current file location, though.

Comment: @WayneWerner That's the correct behavior for a file opened in 'a' mode.

Comment: @zwol I stand corrected. I guess I've always opened in append mode and then done a seek to wherever and truncated the file, so I *was* at the end of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want to do is not possible.  This is a limitation at a lower level than Python, in the operating system.  Neither the Unix nor the Windows file access API offers any way to insert new bytes in the middle of a file without overwriting the bytes that were already there.

Reading the rest of the file and rewriting it is the usual workaround.  Actually, the usual workaround is to rewrite the *entire file* under a new name and then use `rename` to move it back to the old name.  On Unix, this accomplishes an *atomic* file update - unless the computer crashes, concurrent readers will see either the new file or the old file, not some hybrid.  (Windows, sadly, *still* does not allow you to `rename` over a name that already exists, so if you use this strategy you have to delete the old file first, opening an unavoidable race window where the file might appear not to exist at all.)

Yes, this is O(N), and yes, if you use the write-new-file-and-rename strategy it temporarily consumes scratch disk space equal to the size of the file (old or new, whichever is larger).  That's just how it is.

I haven't thought about it enough to give you even a sketch of the code, but it *should* be possible to use context managers to wrap up the write-new-file-and-rename approach tidily.

Comment: Well, that sucks. Maybe I'll be the one to invent it.

Comment: @SarcasticSully Do you think that there are reason for this? It's not that "yeah nobody thought about this until now", it's that it supporting such an operation would break many other things to the point that it's not deemed worthwhile. For example: consider reading the file to a certain point, and obtain the position using `.tell()`, then you go back and insert some bytes using the API you'd like to have. Now what happens if I seek back to the position I was before? Is the position just shifted backwards? Or do the file do something to keep the position the same? In such case *how*?

Comment: I was merely joking. I'm aware that creating such an API would be a non-trivial task.

Comment: Hey, it could be done. But the file would have to have a lot of hardware level metadata, making it perform slowly under reads. It would either waste a LOT of space on disk blocks or perform poorly under caching. So it would probably not be popular, but it would be really good at performing inserts into the middle of the file.

Comment: If this were done in the traditional Unix manner, it would be a syscall `insert_gap(int fd, off_t position, off_t nbytes)` which inserted `nbytes` zero bytes at `position` in the file referenced by `fd` _and that's all_ -- no lseek magic, byte range locks don't move, unspecified effect on concurrent readers and `mmap`, etc.  The primary reason it doesn't exist is not interaction-with-other-parts-of-the-API concerns but _implementation_ concerns. This would be a very expensive thing to ask some filesystems to do, especially when nbytes is not a multiple of the filesystem block size.

Answer (score 1):

No, the disk doesn't work like you think it does.
You have to remember that your file is stored on disk as one contiguous
chunk of data*
Your disk happens to be wound up in a great big spool, a bit like a record,
but if you were to unwind your file, you'd get something that looks like
this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|            Thing 1. String                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
             ^             ^
^            |             \_,                               ^
|            Start of file    End of File                    |
Start of disk                                          End of disk
```

As you've discovered, there's no way to simply insert data in the middle.
Generally speaking, that wouldn't be possible at all, without physically
altering your disk. And who wants to do that? Especially when just flipping
the magnetic bits on your disk is so much easier and faster. In order to
do what you want to do, you have to read the bytes the you want to
overwrite, then start writing down your new ones. It might look something
like this:

- Open the file
- Seek to the point of insert
- Read the current byte
- Seek backward one byte
- Write down the first byte of the new string
- Read the next byte
- Seek backward one byte
- Write down the next byte of the new string
- Repeat until all the bytes have been written to disk
- close the file

Of course, this might be a little bit on the slow side, due to all the
seeking back & forth in the file. It *might* be faster to read each line,
and then seek back to the previous location in the file. It should be
relatively straightforward to implement something like this in Python,
but as you've discovered, there are system limitations that Python can't
really overcome.

*<sup><sub>Unless the files are fragmented, but we're living in an ideal
world where gravity adheres to 9.8m/s<sup>2</sup> and the Earth is a perfect
sphere.</sub></sup>